# Property references vs. lambdas for getter/setter

Tags: kotlin, lambda, reflection, properties

I need to get and set a property of another class from a method and therefore need to pass in either the property reference of lambdas for the getter and the setter:

1. Passing in the property reference

   `otherInstance::property`
2. Passing in a lambda for the getter and one for the setter:

   `{otherInstance.property} // getter`

   `{value -> otherInstance.property = value} // setter`

I like the first one, because for me the code is easier to read and shorter, but my alarm bells ring when I read about it on the [official documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/kotlin-for-py/member-references-and-reflection.html#property-references), because of the term "reflection". My knowledge from Java is that reflection generally isn't a good thing. Is that also valid with Kotlin? Is it valid with this case? Is one of both ways (property reference or lambdas) more performant or more safe?

Answer (score 2):

By using `KMutableProperty0` you would technically be exposing an object that can be used for reflection. If you want to be strict about avoiding reflection, you could use the separate function references for the getter and setter. Note that it's not necessary to pass a lambda as a function reference to a higher-order function. The compiler can interpret property references as functions if the effective signature matches. This would unfortunately mean having to pass the property reference twice. Unfortunately, the setter has to be retrieved via what is technically reflection in this case:

```
class Test (var x: Int)

fun foo(getter: () -> Int, setter: (Int) -> Unit) {
    //...
}

val test = Test(1)
foo(test::x, test::x.setter)

// Zero reflection call:
foo(test::x) { test.x = it }
```

At some point you have to question how badly you want to avoid reflection, because the above code looks very messy to me. If your class takes a `KMutableProperty0` reference, it is much simpler to use. As long as your receiving function isn't using the reference to introspect the code, and only calls `get()` or `set()` on it, you are not really using reflection in the ways that are suggested should be avoided.

```
fun foo(property: KMutableProperty0<Int>) {
    //...
}

val test = Test(1)
foo(test::x)
```

Answer (score 1):

The documentation is about *Member references and reflection*,

If you are referring to *Property references* which isn't using reflection itself,

Reflection is only referred in different section [Obtaining member references from a class reference](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/kotlin-for-py/member-references-and-reflection.html#obtaining-member-references-from-a-class-reference)

> dynamically inspect an object to **see e.g. what properties and functions it contains and which annotations exist on them. This is called reflection**, and it's not very performant, so avoid it unless you really need it.
>
> Kotlin has got its own reflection library (kotlin-reflect.jar must be included in your build). When targeting the JVM, you can also use the Java reflection facilities. Note that the **Kotlin reflection isn't quite feature-complete yet** - in particular, you can't use it to inspect built-in classes like String.

Comment: Property references can be used for reflection. You can use a `KMutableProperty` to get annotations, the name of the property, and various characteristics of the declared property.

Comment: @Tenfour04 But Property references isn't using reflection  *The result is an object which represents a reference to the property (the "Platonic ideal" property, not a property on a particular instance)*

Comment: I guess it depends what is meant by "reflection". If it's merely the ability to introspect code, then a `KProperty` fits the definition. Regardless, if the OP's function needs a reference to actually call, they will need a property from a specific instance (`KMutableProperty1`), not the platonic ideal version (`KMutableProperty`).